# Android restrict fragments only one time go to back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

Hello guys I'm using `BottomNavigationView`. Each item of `BottomNavigationView` will open a fragment which will store in back-stack, But if a item selected multiple times back-stack will store latest instance of that fragment. I mean when pressing back button fragment will open one time only.

Such as, there are 3 fragments..A,B,C

> Fragment pattern: A-B-C-B-A-C-A-C
>
> Back press output should be: C-A-B-exit
>
> But  I will get this pattern- C-A-C-A-B-C-B-A-exit

**Here is the code which I'm using-**

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_home:
            mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Fragment_Home");
            if(!(mFragment!=null && mFragment.isVisible())){
                mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate("Fragment_Home", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment(), "Fragment_Home").addToBackStack("Fragment_Home").commit();
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.nav_account:
            mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Fragment_Account");
            if(!(mFragment != null && mFragment.isVisible())){
                mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate("Fragment_Account", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new AccountFragment(), "Fragment_Account").addToBackStack("Fragment_Account").commit();
            }
            return true;
        case R.id.nav_category:
            mFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Fragment_Category");
            if(!(mFragment != null && mFragment.isVisible())){
                mFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate("Fragment_Category", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new CategoryFragment(), "Fragment_Category").addToBackStack("Fragment_Category").commit();
            }
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);           
    }
    else if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    else if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        finishAffinity();
    }
    else {
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

Give me some idea whats wrong with my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For this issue, I recommend you use the Viewpager instead of Fragment back-stack.
Firstly, I'll tell you why you should not use Fragment backstack. 
I guess in your code, whenever your Activity is created. You will move to your First Fragment instantly. For example: A - B - C - C - C - C - C or  A - B - C - A -B -C - A -C -B. This will remove the backstack fragment like what your said, whenever your click a fragment again you will create a new one.
Here is some other way to use Viewpager, make the UX much better.
First, I customized my own `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` for better performance

```
public abstract class SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    // Sparse array to keep track of registered fragments in memory
    private SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

    public SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Register the fragment when the item is instantiated
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    // Unregister when the item is inactive
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        registeredFragments.remove(position);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    // Returns the fragment for the position (if instantiated)
    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
        return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }
}
```

Let create `CustomViewPager`

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setMyScroller();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    //down one is added for smooth scrolling

    private void setMyScroller() {
        try {
            Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
            Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
            scroller.setAccessible(true);
            scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class MyScroller extends Scroller {
        public MyScroller(Context context) {
            super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
        }

        @Override
        public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
            super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 350 /*1 secs*/);
        }
    }
}
```

put it in your `XML` file like this:

```
<YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />
```

This is the Adapter of ViewPager:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;
    private BaseFragment mFragment1, mFragment2, mFragment3;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);

        mFragment1= Fragment1.newInstance(0, FRAGMENT_TAG_1);
        mFragment2= Fragment2.newInstance(1, FRAGMENT_TAG_2);
        mFragment3= Fragment3.newInstance(2, FRAGMENT_TAG_3);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return mFragment1;
            case 1:
                return mFragment2;
            case 2:
                return mFragment3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

In your Activity, let init it in the `onCreateView()`

```
        mViewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        mViewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(mFragmentManager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
        mFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mViewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mViewPager.setSaveEnabled(true);
```

When you click into a tab, you just need to use

```
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(NUMBER_OF_TIME);
```

Comment: Main problem is that I have to use bottom Navigation View also do the same thing with my navigation view. so I have to resolve this problem. but anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

What you should be doing is declaring activities A,B & C as "singleTop"

> If an instance of the activity already exists at the top of the current task, the system routes the intent to that instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance of the activity. The activity can be instantiated multiple times, each instance can belong to different tasks, and one task can have multiple instances (but only if the activity at the top of the back stack is not an existing instance of the activity).
>   For example, suppose a task's back stack consists of root activity A with activities B, C, and D on top (the stack is A-B-C-D; D is on top). An intent arrives for an activity of type D. If D has the default "standard" launch mode, a new instance of the class is launched and the stack becomes A-B-C-D-D. However, if D's launch mode is "singleTop", the existing instance of D receives the intent through onNewIntent(), because it's at the top of the stack—the stack remains A-B-C-D. However, if an intent arrives for an activity of type B, then a new instance of B is added to the stack, even if its launch mode is "singleTop".
>
> Note: When a new instance of an activity is created, the user can
>   press the Back button to return to the previous activity. But when an
>   existing instance of an activity handles a new intent, the user cannot
>   press the Back button to return to the state of the activity before
>   the new intent arrived in onNewIntent().

[You should read the documentation here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html)  for more information on the topic

Comment: I am using fragment cause bottom navigation view code will be written a single time also toolbar and navigation code will be written one time.